# How to fix a loop with boolean variable

Tags: python-2.7, boolean, replit

I'm doing a project for a class, and I opted to make a text based game in python. I'm trying to set it up so that the question will loop until the player confirms their choice, and I'm having problems with the while loop in this section.

```
def pc_cls_sc(x):
  # code does some stuff

print "You are sure about" + str(x)
exVar = raw_input("Right?")
  if exVar == "y":
      print "Alright!"
      conf_Class = True
  else:
      print "Ok then."
      conf_Class = False

while conf_Class is False:
    pc_Class = raw_input(#asks some question)
    pc_cls_sc(pc_Class)
```

The rest of this code functions properly, but the loop continues after the conf_Class variable is supposed to be set to true. I have a similar loop earlier in my code, which works just fine. I've tried moving the variable reassignment outside of the pc_cls_sc function, but all it did was cause double output. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Please probvide your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with correkt indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `break` to exit the loop. The code below will keep asking a user for input until they say 'y'.

```
while True:
    x=input("Right? " )
    if (x=='y'):
        break
```